# Mapping JavaScript Object Into An Array Of Hashes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to take a Javascript object and convert it into an array of hashes.

The following works to get just one element of the object and turn it into an array:

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map((item) => item.latitude)
```

Returns: `[51.5165328979492, 51.5990409851074, 51.5990409851074, 51.5165328979492, 51.5098190307617, 51.5128326416016, 51.5098190307617, 51.501766204834, 51.514087677002, 51.4983825683594, 51.5294952392578, 51.5123977661133, 51.5011863708496, 51.5204887390137, 51.514087677002, 51.5117797851562, 51.5139465332031]`

But when I try to create hash elements to make up the array, I get an error:

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map((item) => { x:item.latitude, y:item.longitude })
```

Returns: `Uncaught Error: Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ;`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map((item) => ({ x:item.latitude, y:item.longitude }))
```

Lambda functions returning objects need an extra bracket set () to distinguish them from a function body.

Comment: Thank you very much.  It worked!

Answer (score 3):

You need some parenthesis around the curly brackes, otherwise it is interpreted as block statement in [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map((item) => ({ x: item.latitude, y: item.longitude }));
```

Shorter with destructuring and short properties:

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map(({ latitude: x, longitude: y }) => ({ x, y }));
```

Comment: There is also a ; missing at the end

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesize the body of function to return an object literal expression:

```
 params => ({foo: bar})
```

In your case:

```
const coordinatesArray = items.map((item) => ({ x:item.latitude, y:item.longitude }))
```

More Info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Advanced_Syntax).